# Removing the first 5 characters of each entry of a column STORED PROCEDURE

Tags: mysql, sql, string, postgresql, pgadmin-4

I have the table **reservation** and in that table there is a column called **campground**.
Every entry of the campground column is very similar to the other ones e.g.:

﻿ALBE/Alberta Beach Family RV Park

**Can someone tell me how to remove the first 5 characters of every entry in this column using a stored procedure which removes 5 characters from every entry in this column?**

The code I've tried so far is the following:

```
﻿UPDATE reservation
SET RIGHT(campground, LEN(campground) - 5)
```

Can someone help me creating a stored procedure with the functionality mentioned above?

Thanks!!

Comment: Why a stored procedure?

Comment: mysql or postgres? Please tag only the one database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really want to delete the *first 5 characters* of the string, or do you want to delete everything up to the first forward slash?

The other answers here address your literal question.  *This* answers the question you *might really* be asking (PostgreSQL dialect):

```sql
select substr(campground,position('/' in campground)+1)
from (values
     ('ABC/American Bike Camp')
    ,('ALBE/Alberta Beach Family RV Park')) t(campground)
;
```

```
            substr
------------------------------
 American Bike Camp
 Alberta Beach Family RV Park
(2 rows)
```

Using that expression in an update statement:

```sql
update reservation
set campground = substr(campground,position('/' in campground)+1)
where campground like '%/%'
;
```

(where clause included to ensure it doesn't update rows that have already been updated)

Answer (score 1):

I would just use `substr()`, which makes the expression simpler:

```
substr(campground, 6)
```

Both MySQL and Postgres support this syntax.

If you want an update query, then:

```
update reservation set campground = substr(campground, 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`substring`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html) function with a starting position

```
select substring(campground from 6);
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you can use very simple query:

```
UPDATE reservation
SET campground = MID(campground, 6);
```

In PostgreSQL use `substring` instead `mid`:

```
UPDATE reservation
SET campground = substring(campground, 6);
```

Be careful, this query will change you source data, without rollback option.

Answer (score 0):

You missed to give the column name in your set clause:

```
UPDATE reservation
SET campground = RIGHT(campground, LEN(campground) - 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split_part()` in PostgreSQL

```
UPDATE reservation
   SET campground = split_part(campground, '/', 2)
```